# ¿Como puedo agregarle un setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en react, y me he chocado con un problema. El cual es que se ejecuta muchas veces una misma funcion cuando el usuario cambia algo en el "textarea". ¿Como puedo agregarle un timeout?

```
 <textarea
                    name="descripcion"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Escribe la descripcion aqui"
                    onChange={(event) => this.valueToState(event.target)}
                ></textarea>
```

Comment: agregarle un timeout no es buena idea, puesto que debido a que es un timeout no estara sincronizado con lo que el usuario escribio. te recomiendo nisiquiera pensar en usar un timeout, en su lugar existe el evento `input` que es especializado para cualquier `input` en el que puedas escribir. si te parece mucho la cantidad de vecez que se ejecuta quizas escribes muy rapido. la verdad es que una persona con cierta velocidad de tipeo puede escribir entre 12 y 15 letras por segundo.

Comment: Yo he visto que este tipo de problemas se resuelven implementando "debounce".

Comment: Y cual es el problema?, la funcion de `onChange` es ejecutarse cada vez que detecte un cambio. Ademas react trabaja de esa forma en todos sus `input`s.

Comment: Aquí te recomiendo usar debounce. https://yarnpkg.com/package/@react-hook/debounce

Comment: Amigos! Logre solucionarlo. Era un problema externo a eso, eran unos parametros que estaba pasando en otro .js